# An error when making an interface-implementing class static

Tags: java, arrays, oop, interface, static

Suppose I have a simple interface as defined below:

```
public interface Cipher
{
  public String encode(String original);
  public String decode(String encoded);
}
```

In this example, the interface is for creating a few objects representing different elementary ciphers. One such cipher works by taking a given string and inputting it into a two-dimensional array character by character by starting at the top left of the array and going a across each row before moving to the next. The encode method creates the encoded string by reading this array by going down each column before moving to the next. This is displayed in the code below:

```
public class TopLeftColumnRow implements Cipher
{
public TopLeftColumnRow()
{

}
public String encode(String original)
{
    String encoded = "";
    int dimension;
    int x=0;
    int y=0;
    int pos=0;
    dimension = ((int)Math.ceil(Math.pow((double)original.length(),0.5)));
    String[][] LocalBox = new String[dimension][dimension];
    for(x=0;x<dimension;x++)
    {
        for(y=0;y<dimension;y++)
        {
            try
            {
            LocalBox[x][y]=original.substring(pos,pos+1);
            pos++;
            }catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException ex)
            {
                LocalBox[x][y]="*";
            }//catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException ex)
        }//for(y=0;y<dimension;y++)
    }//for(x=0;x<dimension;x++)             

   for(y=0;y<dimension;y++)
    {
       for(x=0;x<dimension;x++)
       {
           encoded+=LocalBox[x][y];
       }//for(x=0;x<dimension;x++)
    }//for(y=0;y<dimension;y++)
    return encoded;
}//encode

public String decode(String encoded)
{

    int dimension;
    int x=0;
    int y=0;
    int pos=0;
    dimension = ((int)Math.ceil(Math.pow((double)encoded.length(),0.5)));
    String[][] LocalBox = new String[dimension][dimension];
    String decoded="";
    for(x=0;x<dimension;x++)
    {
        for(y=0;y<dimension;y++)
        {
            try
            {
            LocalBox[y][x]=encoded.substring(pos,pos+1);
            pos++;
            }catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException ex)
            {
                LocalBox[y][x]="*";
            }//catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException ex)                           
        }//for(y=0;y<dimension;y++)                
    }//for(x=0;x<dimension;x++)

    for(y=0;y<dimension;y++)
    {
        for(x=0;x<dimension;x++)
        {
            if((LocalBox[y][x].compareTo("*"))!=0)
                decoded+=LocalBox[y][x];
        }//for(x=0;x<dimension;x++)
    }//for(y=0;y<dimension;y++)
    return decoded;
}//decode
}//TopLeftColumnRow
```

Since the encryption algorithm is the exact same every time, and no attributes are being stored, it would make sense to make `TopLeftColumnRow` a `static` class, however doing this like so:

```
public static class TopLeftColumnRow implements Cipher
```

Creates an error. Does Java allow static implementations of an interface in general, or is this a specific error on my part? How do I fix this issue?

Comment: A normal, outer, class is `static` by default, so it doesn't make sense to add the keyword. An inner class can be either static or non-static, so there  you could use the `static`keyword.

Comment: How can a outer class be static???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java has no way of making a top-level class static but you can create a static class by following this steps:

- Make class `final` - Prevents extension of the class since extending a static class makes no sense
- Make constructor `private` - Prevents instantiation by client code as it makes no sense to instantiate a static class
- Declare all members and functions of the class `static` -  Since the class cannot be instantiated no instance methods can be called or instance fields accessed

Example:

```
// A top-level Java class mimicking static class behavior
public final class MyStaticClass {
    private MyStaticClass () { // private constructor
        myStaticMember = 1;
    }
    private static int myStaticMember;
    public static void setMyStaticMember(int val) {
        myStaticMember = val;
    }
    public static int getMyStaticMember() {
        return myStaticMember;
    }
    public static int squareMyStaticMember() {
        return myStaticMember * myStaticMember;
    }
}

public class TestStaticClass {
     public static void main(String []args){
        MyStaticClass.setMyStaticMember(5);
        System.out.println("Static value: " + MyStaticClass.getMyStaticMember());
        System.out.println("Value squared: " + MyStaticClass.squareMyStaticMember());
        // MyStaticClass x = new MyStaticClass(); // results in compile time error
     }
}
```

A good use of a static class is in defining a class where instantiation it would not make sense.If Java allowed top-level classes to be declared static then Java's `Math` class would be static.